Load sync error while using PowerPoint Javascript API
I am trying to add a basic textbox/Geometric shapes into the PowerPoint on click of a button (using Microsoft Add-ins) . I am going through this document provided by Microsoft - Text in shapes.
It works fine however the content doesn't load properly, it is perfectly visible in presentation mode.
If you can see the image here-
In the left pane(where you can see all the slides), I can see the correct result, however in the main page I can only see the shape, not the color. It also looks correct in present mode as well. If I do any change with it manually, then it re-renders into correct shape.
Here's the main code -
export async function insertTextBox() {
  await PowerPoint.run(async (context) => {
    const shapes = context.presentation.slides.getItemAt(0).shapes;
    const braces = shapes.addGeometricShape(PowerPoint.GeometricShapeType.bracePair);
    braces.left = 100;
    braces.top = 400;
    braces.height = 50;
    braces.width = 150;
    braces.name = "Braces";
    braces.fill.setSolidColor("lightblue");
    braces.textFrame.textRange.text = "Shape text";
    braces.textFrame.textRange.font.color = "purple";
    braces.textFrame.verticalAlignment = PowerPoint.TextVerticalAlignment.middleCentered;
    await context.sync();
});
}

One solution is to add await context.sync() multiple times in between, however then it first loads the shape, then the color and then the text and I don't want user to see this change as it is happening.
Correct response-


In your 3rd sentence, where you say "presentation mode", do you mean editing mode? If so please update your post.

Hi , presentation mode means when we present the pptx, so it looks exactly the way I wanted in present mode, however in editing mode there is a delay, it doesn't provide the exact output as shown in the image.

PowerPoint add-ins don't run presentation mode, so it's unclear what the problem is. You can only run an add-in when your are editing the presentation.

Right, So my problem is , I create a shape(or any textbox) using add-In, the shape got created using add-in however, the shape doesn't look correct (It looks like it's 70% done only) .
When I go to present mode, the shape is formed completely . If you see my first image, you can only see the curly braces, which is not the shape that I created. When I go to present mode I can see the correct response -{shape text}. I don't want to go to present mode to properly load the shape correctly, it should be loaded correctly in edit mode itself.
